# kafka kraft cluster is it right to set dedicated controller and dedicated broker on same machine

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

according to documentation ( from https://developer.confluent.io/learn/kraft/ _

"If you want to try it yourself, follow the Kafka Local Quickstart. This quick start runs in KRaft combined mode, meaning that one process acts as both the broker and controller. Combined mode is only appropriate for local development and testing. Refer to the documentation here for details on configuring KRaft for production in isolated mode, meaning controllers run independently from brokers."

so KRaft combined mode is actuality both method as broker and controller on the same PID ( process ID )

we are wondering about different way  like dedicated PID for broker service and dedicated PID for controller service

from our understanding when both PID's are running on the same machine , this gives more stability to the cluster , for example if we stop broker service then controller still up and opposite

am I right here ?

Answer (score 1):

The combined mode is designed to run as one PID. In order to get two PID, you'd effectively run `kafka-server-start` with two different property files, causing two JVMs with similar code to compete for system resources, therefore it's arguably less stable than dedicated machines for each process type.